# Include functions written in different folders

Tags: c++, c++builder, include-path

How can I use a function written within a .cpp saved in a folder different from the one that needs that function? For all the .cpp of the first folder I've simply added an `#include` to the .h of the cpp (and it works fine), but trying to add an `#include "..\Folder1\....h"` to all the .cpp of the second folder is not enough and the Borland C++ Builder gives me the `Unresolved external` error.
What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: add the location of the object files to your linker search path

Comment: @Agnel Kurian - You should put this as your answer :-)

Comment: @trumpetlicks, OK. If anyone knows how it is done on Borland C++ Builder, please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the location of the object files to your linker search path.

[image: Project Options Dialog]

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that I don't know how to do that on Borland C++ Builder

Comment: Does this help (via google)? http://www.webnms.com/cagent/help/porting_guide/compilers/images/setting.jpg

Try "Library path".

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the cpp file into an object file (.o) inside its own directory and link that object file with your program.